# How to detect New File in Existing Folder and take it's directory File VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to process any new file added to an existing folder and take the new file name or the directory name to save it in a text file.

More or less like this:

If (**There is new File** at **Folder "blah"**) then append the **new File Path** to textfile.txt

So I need the new File path
Thanks

Comment: So, VB.NET or VBScript?

Comment: It's vb.net
I using visual studio 2010

Comment: Then you are probably interested in using a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I'am sorry it's still to common for me, can you re-answer it thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what you're trying to do.  You'll want to do the following to test this.
1. Create a windows form
2. Add a button and name it btnStart
3. Add a button and name it btnStop
4. Add a textbox and name it txtFolderToMonitor
5. Add a textbox and name it txtFolderToMoveTo
6. Add a lable and laeve it named Label1
7. Add a textbox and name it TextBox1

Then paste the following as the code behind the form.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private _FilePath As String = String.Empty
    Private _IsProcessing As Boolean = False
    Private _sbJustAPlaceToHoldFileText As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
            Me.btnStop.Enabled = True
            Me.btnStart.Enabled = False
            Me.Label1.Visible = True
            Me.TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
            _FilePath = Me.txtFolderToMonitor.Text
            _IsProcessing = True
            Dim t As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ProcessFoldersContents)
            t.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessFoldersContents()
            While Not Me._IsProcessing = False
                    Dim sfiles() As String
                    sfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Me._FilePath)
                    For Each f As String In sfiles
                            ProcessFile(f)
                    Next
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
            End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessFile(f As String)
            Dim strFileContents As String
            Dim sJustFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)
            strFileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(f)
            Me._sbJustAPlaceToHoldFileText.Append(strFileContents)
            System.IO.File.Move(f, Me.txtFolderToMoveTo.Text & "\" & sJustFileName)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStop_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
            Try
                    Me._IsProcessing = False
                    Me.TextBox1.Text = Me._sbJustAPlaceToHoldFileText.ToString
            Catch ex As Exception
            Finally
                    Me.btnStart.Enabled = True
                    Me.btnStop.Enabled = False
                    Me.Label1.Visible = False
            End Try
    End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: the FileSystemWatcher that vcsjones recommended is much more elegant than my example.  Try to use that.

Comment: "The Path isn't in legal form" it say
where should I put a path for my folder path ?
sorry to bother

Comment: You need to enter a path into the text box that exists on your system before you hit start. Or you can create a directory on your computer like the one that I left in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the approach followed [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58740/FileSystemWatcher-Pure-Chaos-Part-of)? This is pretty exhaustive and addresses some flaws in FileSystemWatcher class.